# PHPExcel - How to write a cell

Tags: phpexcel, barcode

I am trying to write a xls where a cell has a interleaved 2to 5 font content.
For example: for the number 34191091072356016114551671340001571710000323247 the result must be something like !E6\4-#&:;j,-:[$`1Vf0K#"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELGNf.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code. There are hell lot out there to correct

Comment: For the sake of us idiots, can you explain what interleaved 2to5 font content means in simple terms... do you want to embed a barcode n your Excel file?